# How to render a variable inside input type checkbox

Tags: reactjs

I want to check a checkbox based on condition in react JS

My code in render method is -

```
var checkedIn;
        if (this.state.edituserisactive.toString() == "true") {
            checkedIn = "checked";
        } else {
            checkedIn = "";
        }
```

my checkbox code is -

```
<label htmlFor="fgh"> Is Active ? <input className="" type="checkbox" 
style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }} name="edituserisactive"   {...checkedIn} 
onChange={this.onChange} /> </label>
```

I am printing {checkedIn} value then it is showing checked but not working in checkbox input type

Answer (score 0):

```js
<label htmlFor="fgh"> Is Active ? <input className="" type="checkbox" 
style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }} name="edituserisactive" checked={this.state.checkedIn} 
onChange={this.onChange} /> </label>
```

add checked pros depending on your state!

Comment: {this.state.edituserisactive} is boolean value i.e true. so now  ?

Comment: How to add checked as props ?

Comment: checked in react is Boolean so it can be true or false you can assign it  depending on your state!

Answer (score 0):

Setting `checked` to `this.state.edituserisactive.toString()` will cause it be true always because Boolean("false") is true.

You can use the variable directly as a `checked` attribute of the input.

```
const checkedAttr = { checked: this.state.edituserisactive };

<label htmlFor="fgh">
  <input 
    className="classnamehere" 
    type="checkbox" 
    style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }}
    name="edituserisactive" 
    onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} 
    {...checkedAttr}/>
</label> 

onChange() {
  const currentVal = this.state.edituserisactive;
  this.setState({
    edituserisactive: !currentVal;
  });
}
```

Comment: {this.state.edituserisactive} is boolean value i.e true. so now  ?

Comment: @AnuragMishra You can use that boolean value to set the `checked` attribute to true or false.

Comment: Did the same but not working as this.state.edituserisactive prints nothing but this.state.edituserisactive.toString() prints true.

Comment: but we can't deselect the checkbox in this condition

Comment: @AnuragMishra you have to use the onChange handler to toggle its value.

Comment: @AnuragMishra try this checked={this.state.edituserisactive} in the input box.

Comment: @AnuragMishra I will have to see a minimal example of it. Can you put it in a jsFiddle?

Comment: @AnuragMishra Please have a loot at this https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-mendel-94uu2

Comment: Hi Sreeram I am fetching a record from the API then I am assigning the boolean value from coming from API to a state variable like this - 

edituserisactive: data.data.empdetail[0] && data.data.empdetail[0].isactive

where isactive is true.

Comment: It should still work. But I will need to see a minimal representation to debug further.

Comment: But it's not working if I am assigning a boolean value coming from API to edituserisactive

Comment: Is there a repository of this I can see?

Comment: My toggle is working for the first time but when it get checked then toggle not working

Comment: Can you send me you email so that i can send you my whole code ?

Comment: Very large code consists of some other code in the same file as well so can't put in jsfiddle . If you can send me your email please ?

Comment: sent please check